# Creating new file through Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, createfile

I have googled for the below question, but could not find any answer.
Can someone help me on this;
What is the command to create a new file through Windows Powershell?

Comment: what type of `file` are you trying to create? Or in other words what file extension? Like .txt .docx etc...

Comment: @user6811411 These sorts of comments never seem to age well. This question is now the first result when searching "powershell create empty file" on Google.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To create file using echo

```
echo some-text  > filename.txt
```

Example:

```
C:\>echo This is a sample text file > sample.txt
C:\>type sample.txt
This is a sample text file
C:\>
```

To create file using fsutil

```
fsutil file createnew filename number_of_bytes
```

Example:

```
fsutil file createnew sample2.txt 2000
File C:\sample2.txt is created
C:\data>dir
01/23/2016  09:34 PM     2,000 sample2.txt
C:\data>
```

Limitations

Fsutil can be used only by administrators. For non-admin users it throws up below error.

```
c:\>fsutil file /?
```

The FSUTIL utility requires that you have administrative privileges.
    c:>

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please don't suggest the use of `echo` - an alias for the rarely needed `Write-Output` cmdlet - because it is a bad habit to promote in the PowerShell world. Newcomers need to be guided towards PowerShell's _implicit_ output model: `'some-text' > filename.txt`. If your code is meant to be `cmd.exe` code (it also works as that), please note the the question is tagged [tag:powershell].

Answer (score 72):

I'm guessing you're trying to create a text file?

```
New-Item c:\scripts\new_file.txt -type file
```

Where "C:\scripts\new_file.txt" is the fully qualified path including the file name and extension.

Taken from [TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176914.aspx)

Comment: ++, but note that you're not creating a _text_ file, you're creating a _zero-byte_ (empty file) - which has no inherent type.

Comment: This should be the answer. Get, Start, New, and etc is new era of cmdlet that's great for sysadmin. Just left old command behind.

Comment: how to create the file and every directory within the path?

Answer (score 25):

street smart (quick, dirty but works):    (might change the file and add an invisible character which might cause the compiler to fail)

```
$null > file.txt
$null > file.html
```

Textbook method:

```
New-Item -path <path to the destination file> -type file
```

example:

```
New-Item -path "c:\" -type file -name "somefile.txt"
```

OR

```
ni file.xt -type file
```

absence of -path parameter means it creates it in the current working directory

Comment: So many great options, especially short-hand cmd `ni` with working directory

Answer (score 22):

```
ni filename.txt
```

Replace `filename.txt` with your file .

I found this the simplest answer to the question, and refer to other answers for more details.

Comment: Quick thing to point out here is that `ni` is a default alias for the `New-Item` command. Alias information for a specific command can be view via the `gal -definition` command, e.g. `gal -definition New-Item`.

Comment: I really liked this answer. Also ni (New-Item) creates the file with UTF-8 encoding and echo creates it with ucs-2 le bom(UTF-16) encoding. Unless you change the encoding, the files created with echo will be twice the size.

Comment: This is easiest. Note that when running this, my powershell asked for type, I put in `file`

Answer (score 9):

Here is another way to create a blank text file in Powershell which allows you to specify the encoding.

**First example**

For a blank text file:

```
Out-File C:\filename.txt -encoding ascii
```

Without `-encoding ascii`, Powershell defaults to Unicode. You must specify `ascii` if you want it to be readable or editable by another source.

Overwriting the file with new text:

```
"Some Text on first line" | Out-File C:\filename1.txt -encoding ascii
```

This replaces whatever text is in `filename.txt` with `Some Text on first line.`

Appending text to the current file contents:

```
"Some More Text after the old text" | Out-File C:\filename1.txt -encoding ascii -Append
```

Specifying `-Append` leaves the current contents of `filename.txt` alone and adds `Some More Text after the old text` to the end of the file, leaving the current content intact.

Answer (score 3):

As many have already pointed out, you can create files with the `New-File` command.
This command has a default alias set to `ni` but if you're used to unix commands you can create your own custom command easily.

Create a `touch` command to act as `New-File` like this:

```
Set-Alias -Name touch -Value New-Item
```

This new alias will allow you to create new files like so:

```
touch filename.txt
```

This would make these 3 commands equivalent:

```
New-Item filename.txt
ni filename.txt
touch filename.txt
```

Keep in mind that for this to be persistent, you should add the alias to your powershell profile. To get it's location simply run `$profile` on ps. If you want to edit it directly, run `code $profile` (for VSCode), `vim $profile` (for vim) or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it (method I like)

```
New-Item -ItemType file -Value 'This is just a test file' -Path C:\Users\Rick\Desktop\test.txt
```

Source: [New-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?view=powershell-7.1)

Answer (score 2):

Use the **New-item** cmdlet and your new file name.

> `New-item <filename>`

Example:

```
New-item My_newFile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
                                                       # encodings:

New-Item file.js -ItemType File -Value "some content"  # UTF-8

"some content" | Out-File main.js -Encoding utf8       # UTF-8-BOM

echo "some content" > file.js                          # UCS-2 LE BOM
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in any command line:

```
"" > path/to/file/filename.extension
```