# Is there any command to create a python file from terminal window in PyCharm ,in windows OS? need only command, not 2 lines of code

Tags: python, windows-terminal

I am using PyCharm 2023.1.2 edition and I was trying to create a new file from terminal window using create, touch commands but nothing seems to workout .so, if anyone knows how to create a file using command please help me out. Thanks in advance.

I tried to create a file name second using **create second.py**.
create : The term 'create' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- create second.py
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (create:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

and this is happening .

Comment: `ni second.py`?

Comment: `copy NUL second.py` is a bit of a hack, but works easily enough. You're essentially copying 'nothing' into a new file with the given name.

Comment: Your error message looks like Powershell rather than CMD, so see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446285/creating-new-file-through-windows-powershell